How to increase number of workspaces in Debian 12?
I have a Debian 12 system and am wondering how I can increase number of workspaces from 4 to N.

Since not stated otherwise, I assume a gnome desktop installation.
In the "Settings" tool is a section called "Multitasking".
There, you either can let the desktop environment create virtual desktops when needed or specify a fixed amount of desktops present at any time.
